# jQuery tab rotation effect besides toggle?

Tags: jquery, tabs

I have a jQuery slider rotation here: http://8wayrun.com/

Every 5 seconds, the slide changes. I am using this code:

```
$("#recentSlider").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);
```

The problem with this is evident if you look at it on my site; when it changes the slide, it fades out the current slide, then fades in the new slide. So there is a point in time when there is no slide on the screen. Is there a way to make it so that the new slide fades in while the old slide is fading out? So that there isn't any black emptiness?

Comment: I added a little extra info to address the specific code you have here. Follow the link below.

Comment: What is .tabs? I've never seen that before.

Comment: From source code, seems to be jQuery Tools Tabs and not the jQuery UI one

Comment: If you are using third party js plugins then you need to identify them in your question. We shouldn't have to muck through your source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used this plugin, but they provide great documentation. PS - A fiddle would help a ton here.

http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/index.html#effects

You can add your own effects

```
$.tools.tabs.addEffect("default", function(tabIndex, done) {

    // fade out all other panes and fade in new pane
    this.getPanes().animate({ opacity: .3; }).eq(tabIndex).fadeIn();

    // the supplied callback must be called after the effect has finished its job
    done.call();
});
```

And then use it for your tabs effect like so

```
$("#recentSlider").tabs("<pane_selector>", {
    effect: 'myeffect',
});
```